# Why can't my template function be inlined

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, inline

I wrote a class that can store lambda function in it to make sure all resources released before a function exits.

I test my code in `MSVC2015`, `Release` mode with `/O2`.

However, I find that `GenerateScopeGuard` cannot be inlined and a small function is generated.

```
int main()
{
01031C00 55                   push        ebp  
01031C01 8B EC                mov         ebp,esp  
01031C03 51                   push        ecx  
    auto func = GenerateScopeGuard([] {printf("hello\n"); });
01031C04 8D 4D FC             lea         ecx,[func]  
01031C07 E8 24 00 00 00       call        GenerateScopeGuard<<lambda_8b2f3596146f3fc3f8311b4d76487aed> > (01031C30h)  
    return 0;
01031C0C 80 7D FD 00          cmp         byte ptr [ebp-3],0  
01031C10 75 0D                jne         main+1Fh (01031C1Fh)  
01031C12 68 78 61 03 01       push        offset string "hello\n" (01036178h)  
01031C17 E8 24 00 00 00       call        printf (01031C40h)  
01031C1C 83 C4 04             add         esp,4  
01031C1F 33 C0                xor         eax,eax  
}
01031C21 8B E5                mov         esp,ebp  
01031C23 5D                   pop         ebp  
01031C24 C3                   ret  

    return ScopeGuard<T>(std::forward<T>(func));
01031C30 C6 41 01 00          mov         byte ptr [ecx+1],0  
01031C34 8B C1                mov         eax,ecx  
}
01031C36 C3                   ret
```

Looks like exception handling related. Indeed if I disable C++ exception the function is inlined, but don't work with `/EHsc`. Why?

Here is my code.

```
template<typename T>
class ScopeGuard
{
public:
    ScopeGuard(const ScopeGuard&) = delete;
    ScopeGuard& operator=(const ScopeGuard&) = delete;

    explicit ScopeGuard(T&& func) :
        func_(std::forward<T>(func))
    {}

    ScopeGuard(ScopeGuard&& right) :
        func_(std::move(right.func_))
    {}

    ~ScopeGuard()
    {
        if (!dismissed_) func_();
    }

    void Dismiss()
    {
        dismissed_ = true;
    }

private:
    T func_;
    bool dismissed_ = false;
};

template<typename T>
__forceinline ScopeGuard<T> GenerateScopeGuard(T&& func) noexcept
{
    return ScopeGuard<T>(std::forward<T>(func));
}

int main()
{
    auto func = GenerateScopeGuard([] {printf("hello\n"); });
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you turned any optimizing on?

Comment: And please provide the full disass. Does adding `inline` or even `static` help?

Comment: @Surt yes, I compile it with /O2

Comment: @black full disass is provided now. But inline or static does not help

Comment: Oh, it's microsoft :( avoid. Use a proper compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems MSVC compiler is getting confused by recently introduced non static member initialization feature. Constructor with initialization seems to fix the problem:

```
ScopeGuard()
    : dismissed_(false)
{
}
```

Comment: You are right! Though it doesn't work with MSVC2015, I add a member function to init `dismissed_` and call it manually after construction to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Compiling with -O3 -std=c++14:

output from gcc 5.4:

```
.LC0:
        .string "hello"
main:
        subq    $8, %rsp
        movl    $.LC0, %edi
        call    puts
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        addq    $8, %rsp
        ret
```

output from clang 3.8:

```
main:                                   # @main
        pushq   %rax
        movl    $.Lstr, %edi
        callq   puts
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        popq    %rcx
        retq

.Lstr:
        .asciz  "hello"
```

This is without the nonstandard `__forceinline` attribute.

Are you sure you've enabled optimisation?

Is it that this function is generated but not called by main?

Comment: Yes, I compile it with /O2. Maybe it's compiler related

Comment: @Nifury can you post the assembler code emitted for the function main() ?